How to get IntelliJ proxy settings programmatically?
The class HttpConfigurable has been deprecated at version 2024.2, when I use HttpConfigurable.getInstance() to get proxy data such as host, login name, it will warn: 'com. intellij. util. net. HttpConfigurable' is deprecated and marked for removal. Is there other way to get proxy data?
I tried as https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/206755245-How-to-access-IntelliJ-proxy-data-programmatically said, but warning shows when compiling:
warning: [removal] HttpConfigurable in com.intellij.util.net has been deprecated and marked for removal
HttpConfigurable proxySettings = HttpConfigurable.getInstance();

The documentation in HttpConfigurable refers you to the deprecation notices for the specific methods:

/**
* @deprecated Use {@link ProxySettings}, {@link ProxyAuthentication}, {@link HttpConnectionUtils}, and {@link ProxyUtils} instead.
* See method deprecation notices for more details.
* <p/>
* For removal in version 24.3
*/


For example, according to the documentation for getProxyLogin() states that you should use a version of ProxyUtils#getStaticProxyCredentials.

/** @deprecated use {@link ProxyUtils#getStaticProxyCredentials(ProxySettings, ProxyCredentialProvider)} or {@link ProxyUtils#setStaticProxyCredentials(ProxySettings, ProxyCredentialStore, Credentials, boolean)} */
  @Deprecated(forRemoval = true)
  @Transient
  public @Nullable String getProxyLogin() {
    return getSecure("proxy.login");
  }



Thank you!
I tried and found that ProxySettings.getInstance().getProxyConfiguration() can get proxy host and port.
Andf ProxyUtils#getStaticProxyCredentials(ProxySettings.getInstance(),                 (ProxyCredentialProvider) (ProxyCredentialStore.getInstance()))  can get user name and password.
